# Redirect all http requests (including subdomains) to https

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have already tried different solutions from other threads but somehow none is working. So I have a domain called `my-domain.com` and I want that all http requests to `http://my-domain.com` or `http:///*.my-domain.com` are redirected to the corresponding https page. In the folder `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` I have a configuration file which looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName my-domain.com
   ServerAlias *.my-domain.com

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.my-domain\.com$
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1.my-domain.com/$1 [R=302,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

But still there are no redirects. All requests are failing because of a timeout. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `RewriteRule`, the `%1` is not doing what you think it will be doing.

```
# bad
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1.my-domain.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Try this:

```
# good
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

What we are doing here is taking ANY request that is NOT HTTPS, and rewriting it.  We don't care about looking at the `%{HTTP_HOST}`, nor the `%{REQUEST_URI}`, because we will just use them blindly.

This is a "blind forward" to HTTPS.  I don't care what you asked for, but since you did it over HTTP, you will have to do it over HTTPS.

At that point, it becomes a different rule to redirect further.

Additionally, `302` is a **temporary redirect**.  You may wish to consider a `301`, for a **permanent redirect** across ports.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But still it does not work. I am getting the feeling that it does not have to do anything with the apache config. I also cannot see any access logs for http requests. All https requests are working fine. Is there any log file besides the apache access logs where I can see incoming http requests?

Comment: Well, once you solve that problem, at least you will not have this one standing in your way.  You may wish to start another question with different details to debug your other issue.

Comment: Use `RewriteLog` to send rewrite debugging to a file. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPD/RewriteLog

Comment: What's the point of the capture group `(.*)` if it's not referenced?